# How to read input line at the end character or at '\n' character?

Tags: c

How can I read in C a line from the console to not initialize a some array like `int buf[30];`? I need to allocate it once and required length, i.e. to I can know input characters count before read it...
Is it possible in C?

Comment: You can read ahead and then seek the file backwards, if it supports seeking… but that's usually more expensive than several allocation operations. Knowing characters before they're read is obviously impossible. C++, for example, supports reading unlimited characters onto the heap by reallocating O(log(N)) times.

Comment: not in standard C. Posix has an extension: `m` modifier for `scanf`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. And what does the question title mean?

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I know about `seek` in files but how can I do it with `stdin`? I.e. I used `scanf` to find characters count but how can I reset input position to read it again in allocated array?

Comment: Forget about seeking in `stdin`. It is a stream.

Comment: `stdin` is whatever the calling process says it is.

Comment: @Шах Usually `stdin` doesn't support it because it's a pipe. But if it does, it's done just as normal: `stdin` is of type `FILE*`.

Comment: Not that I think that writing user applications in C is a good idea to start with... What would do was to create a ``typedef struct String_tag { size_t capacity; size_t len; char *data; } String_t;`` and write a home brewed ``int getlineString( String_t * target )`` which doubles the capacity whenever it has to "realloc" the data member. Whenever you realloc, double the capacity and start with an initial capacity like 50 or so. Return 0 if something went wrong (e.g. out of memory or EOF) and 1 if it succeeded.

Comment: Thank you all for explanations! I just wanted to know if it's possible or not... and why

Comment: @BitTickler, thank you! I know how to make it with dynamic array allocation, just wanted to know if it has more effective way,

Comment: There is function `ungetc` which pushes a character back to the stream, but horrible practice. Just treat `stdin` as a stream.

Comment: Thank you! I got it is a bad practice to do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to know the number of characters available in standard input before reading them. You can, however, use `getline(3)`, which will read until `\n` and then return the data in a dynamically-allocated buffer holding the data (along with the size of that buffer). You must free the buffer when you're done with it.

You should be aware that this will routine will block until it reads a newline. It's also difficult to use this routine safely, as malformed inputs are not handled well. (What if the input has no newline?) This is one of the reasons many applications often read a fixed length input.

Comment: Very good notes about pros/cons of `getline()`.  To detail: it allows the user - possible hostile - to consume systems resources with an endlessly  _long_ line.  (As you say "What if the input has no newline?")

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that what you are requesting is about ***dynamic memory***. 
With dynamic memory we can create arrays with dynamic capacity, so the number of slots inside can be varied on run-time. That way, you don't need to decide at coding the size of a particular array.

To generate that kind of dynamic array you will need to create a pointer referring to a space in memory.

```
int *array;
```

Once we have that connection between memory and a variable, we now need to set how much memory do we want(how many slots inside the array).

```
array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfSlots);
```

This function ***malloc*** its provided by an external library called stdlib.h.
It will request the computer for a space in the memory. That space is defined inside those brackets (). There you set the number of bytes you want to request.

If what we want is an array of integers, we multiply the size of an integer with the slots we need.

To access or modify data inside an array, you can keep it simple by using [], like this:
array[0] = 1;

***Important note:*** Never access or modify data inside an array without requesting memory before!

To read the numbers of chars in a line, you can simple use a loop, and read letter by letter until you find that '/n' character.